# Sum was simplified and I don't know how it was done

Tags: simplifying-expressions, summation

I want to compute the sum

$\qquad \sum_{i=1}^{n+r}(i+1)n^{i-1}(n+1)^{n+r-i}$

However, when I input the expression

```
Sum[(i + 1)*n^(i - 1)*(n + 1)^(-i + n + r), {i, 1, n + r}]
```

and evaluate it, the output is

> ```
> -2 n^(n + r) - 2 n^(1 + n + r) + 2 (1 + n)^(n + r) + n (1 + n)^(n + r) - 
>   n^(n + r) r
> ```

or

$\qquad -r n^{n+r}-2 n^{n+r}-2 n^{n+r+1}+n (n+1)^{n+r}+2 (n+1)^{n+r}$

Does the result I'm getting mean that Mathematica has already simplified the sum? If so, is there any way to see how it was reduced?

Comment: You can always just check with `FullSimplify`.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica often presents a closed form for a sum if it knows or can compute one.  The only method I know of to see the steps is to use Trace.

```
Trace[Sum[(i + 1)*n^(i - 1)*(n + 1)^(n + r - i), {i, 1, n + r}]]
```

although looking at the results is not all that clear to me. We can check Mathematica's results easily enough for a few examples.

```
FullSimplify[Sum[(i + 1)*n^(i - 1)*(n + 1)^(n + r - i), {i, 1, n + r}]]
(*(n + 2) (n + 1)^(n + r) - n^(n + r) (2 n + r + 2)*)
```

Make a function with the above

```
f1[n_, r_] := (n + 2) (n + 1)^(n + r) - n^(n + r) (2 n + r + 2)
```

Make another function calculating the expression the long way.

```
f2[n_, r_] := Total@Table[(i + 1) n^(i - 1) (n + 1)^(n + r - i), {i, n + r}]
```

Compare the equality of the two forms for several values of `n` and `r`

```
Table[f1[n, r] == f2[n, r], {n, 1, 10}, {r, 1, 10}]
```

The result is a 10 x 10 matrix with all elements `True`.